# Sigma Algebra generated by a finite number of subsets of P(X) is finite

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

As stated in the title, I want to show that the sigma algebra generated by a finite number of subsets of P(X) is finite.  I feel like this should be easy but I am stuck.  I tried showing that it is contained in a finite sigma algebra but I must not be choosing the right one (something like the set of all unions of the generating elements and their complements but I don't think that is right).

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

Let $X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n$ be subsets of $X$. For each $x\in X$ consider the following function $f:X\to\{0,1\}^n$:

$$f(x)_k=\begin{cases}1&\text{ if }x\in X_k\\0&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Let $Y_1,\ldots,Y_{2^n}$ be the preimages of each element in $\{0,1\}^n$.

Note that every set of the $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$ generated by $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ is the union of some of the $Y_k$'s. So $\Sigma$ has at most $2^{2^n}$ sets (they can be less than that, because some $Y_k$'s may be empty).

Comment: Why is every set in the sigma algebra a union of some of the Y's?

Comment: Since the set of generators is finite, infinite unions and infinite intersections are actually finite. So you can easily show this by induction. (If $A$ and $B$ are the union of some $Y$'s, then also are $A\cup B$, $A\cap B$ and $\complement A$).